# Pharo Smalltalk - How can I list all the classes in a Category (aka Package or Tag)?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Pharo Smalltalk - How can I list all the classes in a Category?

In the System Browser, the first pane contains the Category under which all my classes are listed. Is there a list of those classes programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all classes like

```
(RPackageOrganizer default packageNamed: 'Kernel') definedClasses
```

You can also use

```
(RPackageOrganizer default packageNamed: 'Kernel') classTags
```

to get all tags in the package (previously known as `packages`) and for each you can send `#classes` to get the classes of the tag

Comment: I got the first part. Yey! The second one is more elusive, if I do a (RPackageOrganizer default packageNamed: 'SemWhatever') classTags collect: [:each | each classNames] I get the same answer as the first one. What do you mean by 'to get all tags in the package (previously known as packages)'? You mean 'to get all packages in the package (currently known as tags)'? From what I can discern you are telling me that a Class can define "category: 'Whatever'" when you create it, this is then used by the System Browser to group classes together under a 'Package' with the same name.

Comment: ... maybe one and the same as "category: 'Whatever'", which are now or will be in the future named just Tag. Is this correct? (System Browser - Package, Class Category, Class Tag mean exactly the same thing?

Comment: @unmircea prior to Pharo3 each package had categories. Now each package has Tags. The point is that Package is more based on versioning (monticello) idea. While tags provide better categorization. So if you do `#collect:` for all tags - it's the same, but I just gave you an idea how to get classes of a specific tag.